# If statement isnt working even when i set a boolean to automatically be false

Tags: java, if-statement

```
grass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    pm = false;
    if(pm=false){
    drawGrassBlock(x1, y, Color.green, size, size2);
    }
    }
});
```

This is my code and for whatever reason the if statement does nothing....i set the boolean to be false and told it to print a string when inside the if statement but the console wont return anything which means its not properly "getting inside". I told it to print the value of the boolean and its printing false so please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an assignment within the `if`, not an equality comparision. From section ***15.26 Assignment Operators*** of the Java Language Specification:

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable
>   after the assignment has occurred.

meaning the result of `pm = false` is always `false`, so the `if` branch is never entered.

Change to:

```
if (false == pm) // or if (!pm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
if(pm == false)
```

instead of

```
if(pm = false)
```

Using single `=` will set `pm` to `false`
Using double `==` will compare `pm` with `false`